# France long term EU Blue card visa refused on "risk of threat to public order/public security/public health" basis

Tags: visa, france, eu, blue-card, refusal

France D visa for long term on talent passport basis refused on "risk of threat to public order/public security/public health" basis and I have no criminal record and not ever visited Schengen countries. I have appeal option, should I appeal against the decision or submit new visa application?
Also will this refusal effect my future UK visa application and also can face any problems while arriving in UK?
Am a Pakistani national and applied for France visa from UK.

Comment: You may find user Gayot Fow's answer to [this Travel.SE question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57579/schengen-visa-refusal-on-threat-to-public-policy-security-health/66675#66675) informative.

Comment: Consult an Immigration lawyer

Comment: @Traveller My immigration consultant said that they will contact French consulate to gain more information and then will decide whether to appeal or apply again but I read somewhere that appeal can have more serious impacts.

Comment: @Traveller is correct. If you search for "immigration advisor," "travel advisor," or "travel consultant" in the search box at the top of any SE page, you'll find pages and pages of info that non-lawyer non-solicitor advisors often give poor and inaccurate advice. You will get much more accurate information — at a higher cost — by consulting a French lawyer with immigration experience.

Comment: Have you ever applied for a visa to any Schengen country before (especially Switzerland)?

Comment: @ThomasCruise no, I have never been in Schengen country nor I did apply for any visa type for Schengen countries.

Comment: @Stark Ok. I asked because I know a few cases where the same thing happened and it turned out that they had applied to Switzerland in the past and CH had put their name in SIS (Schengen Information System) database. After hiring lawyers, spending time and money, Swiss authorities claimed it happened "by mistake", in every single case and then removed the name from SIS and they were finally able to get visas from the other country. (I am talking about cases of a period of around 3 years and refusals from different Schengen countries). I wanted to make sure it was not another one of those cases.

Comment: @ThomasCruise many thanks for your comment. What you suggest a way forward for me? Am currently getting Police character certificate from Pakistan and also from UK and attached them with appeal as proof of clean criminal record. But  I read somewhere that appealing against such decision may have more consequences. So I don't know should I go with appeal option or apply again for visa and add character certificate as support document.